# How to create multiple customer attributes in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, setup-upgrade, installdata

How to create multiple customer attributes in Magento 2 using InstallData or UpgradeData?

```
<?php


namespace DeviMage\CustomerAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){

        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0) {

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'designation', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Designation',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'designation')
                ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ]]);
            $attribute->save();


            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'landlinenumber', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Landline Number',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'landlinenumber')
                ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ]]);
            $attribute->save();


        }
    }
}
```

What is Difference between InstallData & UpgradeData?

Comment: InstallData is execute when your module installing first time.
UpgradeData is execute when we have updating the module version from module.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hii @Devidas Please try this code

```
$setup->startSetup();

$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
$attributesInfo = [
            'vat_id' => [
                'label' => 'VAT number',
                'type' => 'static',
                'input' => 'text',
                'position' => 140,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ],
            'vat_is_valid' => [
                'label' => 'VAT number validity',
                'visible' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'type' => 'static',
            ],
            'vat_request_id' => [
                'label' => 'VAT number validation request ID',
                'type' => 'static',
                'visible' => false,
                'required' => false,
            ],
            'vat_request_date' => [
                'label' => 'VAT number validation request date',
                'type' => 'static',
                'visible' => false,
                'required' => false,
            ],
            'vat_request_success' => [
                'label' => 'VAT number validation request success',
                'visible' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'type' => 'static',
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);

            $vatIdAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);

             $vatIdAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
              );
             $vatIdAttribute->save();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Birjitsinh Zala

Answer (score 1):

- **InstallSchema** – setup database structure
- **UpgradeData** – upgraded (add/remove) data from table

> ```
> namespace YourModule\ModuleName\Setup;
>
> use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
> use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
> use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
> use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
> use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
>
> class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
> {
>     protected $customerSetupFactory;
>
>     private $eavConfig;
>
>     private $eavSetupFactory;
>
>     private $attributeSetFactory;
>
>     public function __construct(
>         CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
>         Config $eavConfig,
>         EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
>         AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
>     ) {
>         $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
>         $this->eavConfig            = $eavConfig;
>         $this->eavSetupFactory      = $eavSetupFactory;
>         $this->attributeSetFactory  = $attributeSetFactory;
>     }
>
>
>     public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
>     {
>         $setup->startSetup();
>         /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
>         $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
>
>       // Set your module version
>         if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
>             $customerSetup->addAttribute(
>                 Customer::ENTITY,
>                 'delivered_count',
>                 [
>                     'type' => 'varchar',
>                     'label' => 'delivery count',
>                     'input' => 'text',
>                     'required' => false,
>                     'sort_order' => 100,
>                     'visible' => true,
>                     'system' => false,
>                     'user_defined' => true,
>                     'adminhtml_only' => true
>                 ]
>             );
>
>             $customerSetup->addAttribute(
>                 Customer::ENTITY,
>                 'order_count',
>                 [
>                     'type' => 'varchar',
>                     'label' => 'order count',
>                     'input' => 'text',
>                     'required' => false,
>                     'sort_order' => 110,
>                     'visible' => true,
>                     'system' => false,
>                     'user_defined' => true,
>                     'adminhtml_only' => true
>                 ]
>             );
>         }
>
>         $setup->endSetup();
>     }
> }
> ```